# Is VSCode able to display inline syntax highlighting different to its surrounding text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say that I'm viewing a Markdown file with the content

````
```.IPYNB
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
    "vscode": {
     "languageId": "powershell"
    }
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://dub.sh/zza' | ConvertFrom-JSON | Select-Object -ExpandProperty bio"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```
````

This contains 3 different types of code:

1. The

   ````
   ```.IPYNB
   ```
   ````

   is obviously Markdown;
2. The proceeding `.JSON` is Jupyter Notebook content (hence the `.IPYNB`); and
3. The content of the `.IPYNB` file is Markdown containing PowerShell Core (hence the`.PS1`) code.

This is a complex example, but it demonstrates the need for VSCode to be able to intelligently parse these formats to provide syntax highlighting. Is this possible to enable, via an extension or preference?

I ask this because GitHub is actually capable of this to an extent already. For instance, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/937#discussion-5874181 displays:

> [image]

(albeit solely when rendered).

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/937#discussion-5874181

Comment: I don't get it. what do you expect to see? Do you want the Markdown Preview to render a code block of ipynb like it renders a Notebook Editor? Or do you want it to render the JSON? And if the latter, what do you expect to see with the JSON parts describing the PowerShell cells?

Comment: and what do you mean by "different to the surrounding text"? Different in what way? different colour theme? different language mode? Because it can do different language mode in regular text document editors, but not different colour theme.